# Term meaning 'with written words'

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, analogy

In the same way that *verbally* means *with spoken words*, I'm looking for a term that means *with written words*. Is there such a word?

Comment: NB: while *verbally* can mean *with spoken words*, it can also mean *with words* (whether spoken or not).  Some situations will warrant the use of *orally* to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: sir, this is an adverb!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *textual* or *textually* to convey this idea.

Answer (score 11):

How about simply saying *in writing*?

Comment: +1: Or simply *written*, as in "You say you can recite the poem from memory, but I'd like to see a written version just to be sure."

Comment: Or “in cold print” if it should be a bit more dramatic ;)

Answer (score 5):

*Orthographically* may be what you are looking for.